# Bind GridView From Excel File Throws Permission Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to read columns from Excel file (xlsx) and bind the values in GridView. But this throws  the following exception

**The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.**

what is the cause of this problem ?

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xlsx"].ConnectionString;
            // Create the connection object
            OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                // Open connection
                oledbConn.Open();

                // Create OleDbCommand object and select data from worksheet Sheet1
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);

                // Create new OleDbDataAdapter
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                // Create a DataSet which will hold the data extracted from the worksheet.
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                // Fill the DataSet from the data extracted from the worksheet.
                oleda.Fill(ds, "Employees");

                // Bind the data to the GridView
                this.gvExcel.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                this.gvExcel.DataBind();
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close connection
                oledbConn.Close();
            } 
        }
    }
```

aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExcel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: it comming bcz you open you file in excel already close exce it will worl well

Comment: I closed the file but the problem stay the same.

Comment: this error come only bcz of that try to restart your pc  and than run vs

Comment: I restart the PC and the same problem.